# POST to an AEM servlet returns a Content modified message instead of the data

Tags: post, servlets, aem

I have an AEM Servlet that currently accepts GET requests and returns some search results based on a query.  I am trying to change the servlet to accept POST requests as well as GET requests. I made a veey minimal doPost method to start off, just to test if the endpoint works but when I do a POST request I get a message:

`Content modified /content/path/to/page`

My Servlet is called `DataTablesSearchServlet` and I am POSTing to

`http://localhost:4502/content/path/to/page.DataTablesSearchServlet.json`

The doPost method is very simple and just returns a string for now

```
    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            response.getWriter().write("Received POST data");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle any IO exceptions that may occur while reading the POST data
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setStatus(SlingHttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Not sure why it is returning a content modified message instead of just "Received POST data"

Comment: That is default behavior on AEM, if you POST to a /content/mysite/some/path it is interpreted as if you want to write data on that node. Use a /bin/mypostservlet path instead.